# Why does the actual width of a scaled image inside a flex item affect item's width?

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox, css-position, gecko

I was trying to achieve a header with a height proportional to the screen and containing an image with a title. The attempted solution used a row flex layout. The intention is to have the header a proportion of the viewport/parent height (20%). The width of the image *and its parent* should match the scaled image width according to the image's aspect ratio. The title's parent div should occupy the remaining width and grow to fill any available horizontal space.

The container is using fixed positioning with a proportional height.

The actual behaviour in Chrome 54 and Firefox 50 is that the image's parent element occupies most of the container width and this width is dictated by the image's actual width (not the scaled width of the image). I don't understand this when the image is scaled down to a fraction of that width.

Example reproducing this behaviour here: https://jsfiddle.net/uy66as8k/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-view">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/"></img>
  </div>
  <div class="title-view">
    <h1>This is the Title</h1>
  </div>
</div
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.img-view {
  background-color: salmon;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.title-view {
  background-color: cyan;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Desired result:
[image]

Actual result:
[image: Actual result]

Comment: _“I don't understand this when the image is scaled down to a fraction of that width”_ - __because__ the image aspect ratio is respected …? For the image to be _wider_, it would also need to be _higher_, if aspect ratio is to be preserved. But the height is restricted by the height of your container element and max-height: 100% on the image.

Comment: Could you post an example of the desired end result please...?

Comment: I have added images for the observed and desired results. I also updated the question to try and clarify that I do not want the image to be wider - I want the container's width to match it so the title pane can fill the extra space.

Comment: I'm on Safari on iPad and can't reproduce the problem. Have you tried simply removing the image container and making the image the child of the flex container? In other words, the image as flex item?

Comment: I can't be reproduce with Safari on macOS 10.11.6 either. Using the `img` as the flex item and avoiding the parent `div` gives the desired outcome for this example but doesn't explain the behaviour in the question and isn't a practical solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just set your image container to have a height of 100%.

```
.img-view {
  height: 100%;
  ...
}
```

**Explanation:** Okay so first and foremost you have your container set at 20% of whatever its parent is. In this case its the body. You're pulling in images with random dimensions so you're encountering a situation where their dimensions are exceed their parent containers (`.container`, `.image-view`).

The `max-height/max-width` properties that are assigned to all the images won't know its max until you explicitly set a height on its parent (`.image-view`). Once that's done it'll constrain itself properly as seen in the fiddle below.

https://jsfiddle.net/uy66as8k/3/

Comment: Is it possible to answer the "why" in the question? I'm still unable to understand clearly why the behaviour occurred and how `height: 100%` on the parent makes a difference here.

Comment: Posted my answer and got pulled away. There's also some stuff in there you don't need that I need to take a look at again. Gimme a few minutes to write up the explination.

Comment: I understand the explanation however I'm not sure it explains the original behaviour fully. If I set the height to `90px` instead of `20%`, the problem still occurs. Also, the img did seem to know its max height as it scaled down correctly. The issue the browsers had was with setting the width on the `img-view`.

Comment: @Eoin Do you need a container for your image?

Comment: the container is required for my case and the question is to explain the behaviour with the container. It has been established that the result can be achieved without it.